# Running SQLJ procedure on third party tool

Tags: stored-procedures, db2

How can we execute `call sqlj.install_jar('jarpath','jarname','0');` procedure on third party java tools?

I am trying to run this procedure on DBeaver to install the jar file.

But error I am getting:

> - No authorized routine named "SQLJ.INSTALL_JAR" of type "PROCEDURE" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884

Is it possible to execute the sqlj commands on third party tool?

I used to install it by logging into Db2 server and execute the command.

Comment: Your description of the problem is not clear absolutely. Nobody can help you, if the only description of your problem is "not working". Why do you add db2jcc.jar with this routine, if your third party tool must have its own jar(s)? Namely this jar must be added with this routine. Does this "tool" itself require the database connection, and how does it use this connection exactly? How did you add this jar exactly? Please, edit your question with all such an information.

Comment: @MarkBarinstein Updated the querstion

Comment: Can you run the query in the DB2CMD window (if MS-Windows) or bash shell (if Linux)?   (you may need to omit the third argument if calling from the shell).

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a routine with 3 parameters indeed.
Refer to the following link:
[JAR file administration on the database server](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.routines.doc/doc/r0006425.html).

```
CALL sqlj.install_jar('file:/home/bob/bobsjar.jar', 'MYJAR')
```

Jar file must be accessible from the database server by the full path provided with the 1-st parameter.

Comment: As you mentioned "Jar must be accessible from the the database server..." So I must be installed on DB server side only right

Comment: I didn't get your question. If you call this procedure with 1-st parameter specified as above, the file `/home/bob/bobsjar.jar` must be readable by the db2 instance fenced user on the database server. You may do the same using your java application using the `installDB2JavaStoredProcedure` method of the [DB2Connection interface](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0021824.html). Jar file must be accessible from the workstation running such an application in this case.